# How to use PHP Simple HTML DOM to get data from a remote page traced by a $_GET item?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

When a link in A.html is clicked :

```
<tr>
<td class="book"><a class="booklink" ref="../collection?file=book1.pdf">
Good Read
</a>
-Blah blah blah
</td>  
</tr>
```

?file=book1.pdf is passed to B.html:

```
<?php
$src = $_GET['file'];
?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $src; ?>" >
</iframe>
```

QUESTION:- How to retrieve the text "Good Read-Blah blah blah" from A.html and paste it into the meta description in B.html by using simple html dom? (Please know that there are thousand of listed data in the table in A.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at php dom .. that should help you :)

Comment: Please review this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: I have spent hours to check on the link you suggested but it is too far away from getting the answer because this is not a scraping job at all. More weeds and get higher, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to [load your HTML document](https://www.php.net/domdocument.loadhtml) and [XPath to search it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).

```
// note: if the HTML to parse has bad syntax, use: libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('A.html'));
if ($doc === false) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Could not load HTML');
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpathResult = $xpath->query("//a[@href = '../collection?file={$_GET['file']}']/..");
if ($xpathResult === false) {
    throw new LogicException('Something went wrong querying the document!');
}

foreach ($xpathResult as $domNode) {
    echo 'Link text: ' . htmlentities($domNode->textContent) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: When I run my code, it does get the link text. I changed three things to make it run as an example: replaced `file_get_contents()` with the actual HTML (since I don't have the file A.html), added `$_GET['file'] = 'book1.pdf';` and changed the `ref` attribute in the HTML with `href` (since I assume that was a typo). [Test it yourself](http://codepad.org/4RO1i6Lv), you'll see that it works.

Comment: Well, as the warning message says, that is a problem in the HTML. It is really not a problem in the PHP code. Can you not search for yourself the warning message to find out what it means and to correct or suppress it? Use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` to prevent the errors from being shown.

Comment: What the code now looks for is the link (<a href...>). If you want to include the "Blah..." in your example, that means you need the HTML above it as well (the <td> element). Adding /`..` to the XPath query will search as it does now and then go one element higher. I've modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have tried $xpath->query("//td[@class = 'book']/a[@href = '../collection?file={$_GET['file']}']/..") but still, only "Good Read" comes out, "-Blah blah blah" is still missing. Please tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: (Your XPath still searches for only the <a> element, not the surrounding <td> element. Adding the "td[@class = ....]" in front of it just verifies that the <td> is present, but it does not select it.)

Comment: Haha! I didn't see that "/.." added at the back. Now it works so beautifully!

Comment: Now one last problem:- How to get the different originated path of different $_GET['read'] and paste it into $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('../booksgenre/__________')) without quoting a fixed one? This is necessary because there are thousands of links listed in hundreds of html pages in that booksgenre folder.